# Writing simple upstart script

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I'm trying to write a simple upstart script for my ubuntu server, which starts vnc4server. But it does not work.

Here's the script:

```
# vnc-server.conf

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
        su skerit -c 'vnc4server :0 -geometry 1024x768'
end script

post-stop script
        su skerit -c 'vnc4server -kill :0'
end script

#End of File
```

The command in the first script block works fine when executing it in the terminal, but running `start vnc-server` does not have the same effect.

Comment: check dmesg for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the documentation I've read says upstart shouldn't work this way, I had to place the command in a 'post-start script' block in stead of a regular 'script' block.

So:

```
post-start script
        su skerit -c 'vnc4server :0 -geometry 1024x768'
end script
```

That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a `PATH` issue? Try giving the full path to `vnc4server` in the script. You can find the full path through

```
which vnc4server
```

Disclaimer: have not used upstart.

Comment: Hmm, I've changed the command to /usr/bin/vnc4server, but it still does not work. So that's not it I'm afraid.